# How would I get data of the following format?

Tags: javascript

Wed, 26 May 2010 03:57:59 GMT

Comment: Try yourself please before asking people.

Comment: Already tried http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+date ? (:

Comment: FYI: this exact question (exact wording) was asked a short while ago and was quickly deleted by a moderator, along with a suspension on the user account.

Comment: then check this http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=javascript+date+format&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var d=new Date();
document.write(d.toUTCString());

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var d=new Date();
 alert(d.toUTCString());
```